# Next and Previous Buttons for a JavaScript String Generator

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, string, button

I have a text generator where users can choose the direction that they run through an array of strings. No matter which way you go, it will always loop around to the start.

I've figured out a way to change the direction of the array with different buttons, but now there's a problem with reversing the process either direction. When clicking the reverse button after going forwards (and visa versa), there is a delay in the process. It will move one item in the wrong direction before moving through the array in the correct direction. Try the snippet below for clarity.

```js
var oddprocess = [
    '0',
    '1',
    '2',
    '3',
    '4',
    '5',
    '6',
    '7',
    '8',
    '9',
];


//variables
var processFor = 0;
var counterFor = 0;

function prevProc() {
    document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = oddprocess[processFor];
    processFor--;
    if(processFor < 0) processFor = oddprocess.length - 1;
    //counter
    document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = (counterFor + '&nbsp;/&nbsp;' + (oddprocess.length - 1));
    counterFor--;
    if(counterFor < 0) counterFor = oddprocess.length - 1;
}
document.getElementById('button02').addEventListener('click', prevProc);


function nextProc() {
    document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = oddprocess[processFor];
    processFor++;
    if(processFor >= oddprocess.length) processFor = 0;
    //counter
    document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = (counterFor + '&nbsp;/&nbsp;' + (oddprocess.length - 1));
    counterFor++;
    if(counterFor >= oddprocess.length) counterFor = 0;
}
document.getElementById('button01').addEventListener('click', nextProc);
```

```html
<div class="center" id='display'></div>

<button id="button02"><b>Back</b></button>
<b><font style="color:#000;" id="counter"></font></b>
<button id="button01"><b>Forth</b></button>
```

**How can my code be changed so pushing either button will reverse the direction immediately?**

Answer (score 0):

You only need a single variable to track the `currentIndex` which can be used for both retrieving the string and display in the counter. You also need to increment or decrement the index variable before retrieving the new string to display.

You can also save yourself querying the DOM on every click by storing the relevant elements before adding the listeners.

```js
var oddprocess = [
    '0',
    '1',
    '2',
    '3',
    '4',
    '5',
    '6',
    '7',
    '8',
    '9',
];


//variables
const display = document.getElementById('display');
const counter = document.getElementById('counter');

let currentIndex = 0;

function prevProc() {
    currentIndex--;
    if(currentIndex < 0) currentIndex = oddprocess.length - 1;
    
    display.innerHTML = oddprocess[currentIndex];
    //counter
    counter.innerHTML = (currentIndex + '&nbsp;/&nbsp;' + (oddprocess.length - 1));
}
document.getElementById('button02').addEventListener('click', prevProc);


function nextProc() {
    currentIndex++;
    if(currentIndex >= oddprocess.length) currentIndex = 0;
    
    display.innerHTML = oddprocess[currentIndex];
    //counter
    document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = (currentIndex + '&nbsp;/&nbsp;' + (oddprocess.length - 1));
}
document.getElementById('button01').addEventListener('click', nextProc);
```

```html
<div class="center" id='display'></div>

<button id="button02"><b>Back</b></button>
<b><font style="color:#000;" id="counter"></font></b>
<button id="button01"><b>Forth</b></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because you change the `document.getElementById('display').innerHTML` before changing the value of `processFor`.

Have a look at below code that does what you're trying to achieve.

```js
const DISPLAY = document.getElementById("display")
const COUNTER = document.getElementById("counter")
const PREV = document.getElementById("prev")
const NEXT = document.getElementById("next")

const data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

let pointer = 0; // initial value of the pointer

function displayCurrentValue() {
    DISPLAY.innerHTML = data[pointer];
}

function renderCounter() {
    const text = `${pointer + 1}/${data.length}`
  COUNTER.innerHTML = text
}

// run it to render the initial state
displayCurrentValue()
renderCounter()

PREV.addEventListener("click", () => {
    pointer-- // first change the state (pointer)
  if (pointer < 0) pointer = data.length - 1
  displayCurrentValue() // then act on it
  renderCounter()
})

NEXT.addEventListener("click", () => {
    pointer++ // first change the state (pointer)
  if (pointer >= data.length) pointer = 0
  displayCurrentValue() // then act on it
  renderCounter()
})
```

```html
<div id="display"></div>

<button id="prev">prev</button>
<span id="counter"></span>
<button id="next">next</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to simplify your script and handle both buttons with the same script. Depending on the button-text a click will then either increment or decrement the index of the currently displayed element:

```js
var oddprocess = 'zero,one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,nine'.split(','),       
    opl=oddprocess.length;
//variables
var processFor = -1,
    disp=document.getElementById('display'),
    cntr=document.getElementById('counter');

function step(ev) {
    if (ev.target.tagName=="BUTTON"){
      let inc=(ev.target.textContent=="Back"?-1:1);
      processFor=(processFor+inc+opl)%opl;
      disp.innerHTML = oddprocess[processFor];
      cntr.innerHTML = processFor + '&nbsp;/&nbsp;' + (opl - 1);
}}
document.addEventListener('click',step)
step({target:{tagName:"BUTTON"}});
```

```css
button, span {font-weight:900}
```

```html
<div class="center" id="display"></div>

<button>Back</button>
<span id="counter"></span>
<button>Forth</button>
```